# Create a Python 3 virtual environment

Tags: ubuntu, python, virtualenv

I installed `python3-virtualenv` on Lubuntu 15.1 using the official Ubuntu package `apt-get install python3-virtualenv`. The [official documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#usage) indicates that a simple `virtualenv .` in my project directory should be enough to create the venv. This does nothing, because `which virtualenv` does nothing. (Nothing from `which python-virtualenv` and `which python3-virtualenv` also).

The package information, once installed, says that it installed `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py`, so I invoke this under python3. It gives me this:

```
$ python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py .
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in ./bin/python2
Also creating executable in ./bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

Yep, when I look, everything in ./bin is python2. Is ubuntu's python3-virtualenv a dummy package for python2?

The official python documentation says use a different package: [python3-venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). This seems to work when I `pyvenv .`, with python3 stuff in the `./bin` directory.

How can I successfully create a Python 3 virtualenv?

Comment: The patch that changes this behavior in Debian. https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/modules/python-virtualenv/blob/master/debian/patches/python2-default.patch I wish I understood the thought process used when this patch was added.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`venv` is a convenience script to create virtual envs, but does not fully replace everything `virtualenv` can do.  Using either is fine for most cases though.  `virtualenv` is not obsolete.

`python3 -m venv` works after installing `python3-venv` because Debian strips out some scripts from the base Python package.  `python3-virtualenv` doesn't put the `virtualenv` script on your path for some reason, but `python-virtualenv` does, and will work fine for either version.

It is not important which version `virtualenv` is installed for, it can produce envs for any installed version by passing `-p pythonX` (where X is the version).  `venv`, being more simple, will only create envs of the version it is run from, and is only available since 3.3.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
$ virtualenv -p python3 env
$ source ./env/bin/activate
```

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-venv
$ python3 -m venv env
$ source ./env/bin/activate
```